# How long has GNU kill(1) accepted a name argument?

Tags: kill

We recently discovered that GNU kill, going beyond [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/kill.html), [will take a name as its argument and try to kill all processes with that name](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?kill), in the same vein as pkill(1) or some implementations of killall.

I haven't been able to find GNU's changelog for kill. When was that "feature" added?

Comment: Neither my builtin kill nor /bin/kill ("procps version 3.2.8") accept a name...?

Comment: @Kevin thanks for the feedback. I added a link to the manpage that matches the version of kill I'm dealing with. (If I read that correctly the feature was introduced by Salvatore Valente, which I didn't notice before. I suppose I could email him, but that seems presumptuous when there must be a changelog out there somewhere.)

Comment: the man page you have mentioned is man page for bsd kill and not for gnu kill.

Comment: From FreeBSD 2.1 `killall` does that. (It does something different on Solaris, and make ***sure*** you understand the difference!)

Comment: @SachinDivekar It's not BSD kill either. That particular implementation of `kill` is specific to Linux, and the feature doesn't seem to have existed on classic BSD either (e.g. [4.4BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kill&sektion=1&manpath=4.4BSD+Lite2)).

Comment: @Gilles, yes you are right. I checked the man page again. It says **Linux Utilities** at the bottom left. Plus in AUTHER section it is mentioned that **Taken from BSD 4.4.  The ability to translate process names to  process ids was added by Salvatore Valente**. So, the man page is for Linux and it is taken and updated from BSD 4.4 version.

Comment: Indeed, I would expect a BSD version of `kill` to behave the same as the `kill` on OS X. The `kill` in question does not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can browse the source of [Gnu coreutils on Savannah](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/coreutils/) (or clone the repository on your machine), and in particular look at the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/kill.c) and the [changelog](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/log/src/kill.c) of the `kill` utility. There is not and has never been such a feature.

```
do {
      intmax_t n = (errno = 0, strtoimax (arg, &endp, 10));
      …
      if (errno == ERANGE || pid != n || arg == endp || *endp)
        {
          error (0, 0, _("%s: invalid process id"), arg);
          status = EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
      …
} while ((arg = *++argv));
```

The [manpage you link to](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?kill) is for the `kill` command from the [util-linux collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux). As you can see from the date of the man page, this feature is very old. Many Linux systems ship the `kill` command from GNU coreutils, or the one from the [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) package, and most of the time you'll see your shell's builtin rather than the external command anyway. None of these allow you to pass a bare command name as an argument.

On a related note, in bash, ksh and zsh, you can pass any job specification as an argument to `kill`. Job specifications start with a `%` and can be followed by a job number or by a part of the name of the command of that job.

```
$ jobs
[3] +  Running                 sleep 9999 &
[2] - Stopped                  vim foo
[1]    Running                 xterm &
$ kill %sleep
[3] + Terminated               sleep 9999 &
$ jobs
[2] + Stopped                  vim foo
[1] -  Running                 xterm &
```

Comment: What happened here is that someone used `sudo kill java` when he meant to do `sudo killjava` (where `killjava` is a local script). Sudo bypassed the shell builtin, and I was trying to figure out why `/bin/kill` behaved differently. I'm surprised, but pleased, to discover that GNU was not the culprit this time.